# void loop executes even when the while loop inside is true in arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, c, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I made a simple mobile application to send LED_ON or LED_OFF when a button is clicked. In the below code the while loop is not fully completed while execution but the controller is going to the void loop() and continuing from there.

```
char command;
String my_final="LED_OFF";
#define led 9

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("ready");
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    my_final = "";
    while(Serial.available() > 0){
      command = (byte)Serial.read();
      my_final += command;
      Serial.println("test");
    }
    Serial.println(my_final);
    }

  if(my_final == "LED_ON"){
    Serial.println(my_final);
    analogWrite(led, 255);
    my_final == "LED_ON";
  }

  if(my_final == "LED_OFF"){
    Serial.println(my_final);
    analogWrite(led, 0);
    my_final == "LED_OFF";
  }
}
```

The main problem happens in `my_final=""` as i have to do this to accept new input from the bluetooth. i just cant seem to find a way around this problem.

**EDIT**

This is what im getting in the serial monitor. `test L test E test D test _ test O test N`.

Comment: What you describe in your question is pretty much impossible. Have you really seen in the debugger that the execution exits the `while` loop with condition `Serial.available()` still being true?

Comment: this is what im getting in the serial monitor..
`test L test E test D test _ test O test N`

Comment: Perhaps you should state *what* you're getting in the serial monitor in your question then. Currently, your question reads as if you have seen the execution jump out of the `while` loop, which is impossible to see with a serial monitor.

Comment: What is `my_final == "LED_ON";` supposed to do?  (at the end of the `if(my_final == "LED_ON"){}` block, and likewise for `OFF`)

Comment: How do you know the while loop is fully completed?

Comment: I forgot to remove those two lines which I used before this for some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Serial communication is transmitting data one byte at a time. Your code is fast enough to read and process one byte before the next one is received.

There are many possible solutions to this, and using delays is not a good one.

You could send a marker character at the end of each command, e.g. `LED_ON!`. Then you know you have to keep adding characters to your array until you see an exclamation mark. A common candidate for a marker is the newline character.

Another solution is to make sure all commands have the same length (e.g. 6 bytes). Then you could simply wait until you receive so many characters, that is

```
if(Serial.available() >= 6) ...
```

Beware that in the second solution, if you lose a single byte you will not be able to receive commands correctly until you re-sync. In order to re-sync, you could for example throw away the contents of `Serial` after a timeout, if an incomplete command is sitting there for too long.

Comment: Another option: shift characters into a buffer one at a time, dropping the oldest one for each new one, and check to see if the content of the buffer is a valid command.  Or use single character commands.

Comment: @Jules using a circular buffer would require a guarantee that commands cannot contains other commands as sub-strings.

Comment: A more extensible protocol might be to reserve the first few (1 to 4, depending upon the max expected command/message length) bytes for encoding the length of the message.  Then your algorithm is basically 'read the message size -> read the message'.

Comment: @aroth Sure, that is also possible. Re-sync algorithm would still be needed though.

Answer (score 5):

@9600 Baudrate, you are receiving data at 10 bits per millisecond. One character is 8 bits + start and stop bits in a frame. You are reading the buffer faster than it. So a simple solution would be to put a delay of > 1 ms or so after serial read(), inside the loop.

Comment: This is perhaps the simplest thing the OP could try to confirm the source of their problem. In the long run however, I wouldn't recommend it. There are so many ways in which delay-based code can fail...

Comment: Yes true... data loss can occur when operating at higher baud rate with continuous data stream...

Comment: Yep. Buffer Overflow in that case. Agreed.

Comment: avoiding buffer overflow can be done by only `delay(1)`ing after the `read()` when `Serial.available() == 0`

Comment: @MITURAJ I actually meant something else. When you write a string like "LED_OFF" to a COM port on a computer, there's no guarantee that all characters will be sent without delay. The same is true for microcontrollers where the UART ISR doesn't have the highest priority.

Answer (score 2):

Buffering until a linefeed might look like this (my arduino code is a bit rusty, so please forgive simple errors - the algorithm should be correct):

```
finished = false;
command = "";
while (!finished) {
   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      c = (byte)Serial.read();
      if (c == '\n') {
         finished = true;
      }
      else {
         command += c;
      }
   }
}
```

This loop will just keep reading characters and adding these characters to the variable command.

This assumes that the communications link is perfect, in that it will not drop or mangle characters. To make this more robust, you could put a check in to make sure that the time to receive the command isn't too long.

You also might want to respond to each command with either an ack response or a huh? (nack) response, letting the server know what's going on.

Happy making!

Answer (score 1):

What happens when the incoming datastream looks like this:

`LE`..Td..`D_O`..Td..`N`?

*Td* is a random small delay.

If your `while(Serial.available() > 0){` is faster than Td, you will have reset `my_final = "";` with only `LE` in it. Meaning, next you receive `D_O`, and then you reset it again.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem im facing here. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: @ganeshvicky Buffer until line feed.

Comment: You mean use the delay() function? Im sorry im sort of new to this.

Comment: @ganeshvicky No, with delay you can't read the serial port. you need to buffer until you receive a `\n`, but you will still have to poll `Serial.available()`, so you will have to figure something out.